# How can you match background of a div to its window background color with a slight tint?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web project and I'm wondering wonder how I can create a container, that matches a colorful complex background (and is in sync while changing website width and height), with a size of 80% wide and 80% high of viewport size.

Do I create a div that has a transparent background? Here are a few shots from Dribble to show you what I mean.

[image: Example]

[image: Second example]

That's what I am trying to achieve.

**Update**
With the answer provided, here's what I've done so far (on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/graffis/pen/ZEGoOdm)):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#on_top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient( 160deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 21%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 0.15) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 19px 35px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  box-shadow: 0px 19px 35px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
}

.background {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.green-pics {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  background: white;
}

.yellow-pics {
  grid-column: 5/7;
  grid-row: 3/6;
  background: white;
}

.red-pics {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 3/6;
  background: white;
}

.green-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 4/6;
  background: #6637cf;
}

.yellow-text {
  grid-column: 4/7;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  background: #0cdbfd;
}

.red-text {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/6;
  background: #d00c22;
}

.blue-text {
  grid-column: 5/7;
  grid-row: 6/9;
  background: #0055d2;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1/5;
  grid-row: 6/9;
  background: grey;
}

.green-text p {
  font-size: 36px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  color: white;
}

.green-text button {
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="green-pics pics content"></div>
  <div class="yellow-pics pics content"></div>
  <div class="red-pics pics content"></div>
  <div class="green-text text content"></div>
  <div class="yellow-text text content"></div>
  <div class="red-text text content"></div>
  <div class="blue-text text content"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>

<!-- Your translucent container -->
<div id="on_top">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="green-pics pics content"></div>
    <div class="yellow-pics pics content"></div>
    <div class="red-pics pics content"></div>
    <div class="green-text text content">
      <p>Go to store</p>
      <button><a href="store.html">BUY</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="yellow-text text content"></div>
    <div class="red-text text content"></div>
    <div class="blue-text text content"></div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's what I would like to achieve: Fully working webiste (inside 80x80 container) with matching background:
[image: Final effect]

Comment: Hi @Graffis,
hm, I haven't worked with those technologies myself, yet, but perhaps `clip-path` and `blend-mode` could get you started.
See https://css-tricks.com/weaving-one-element-over-and-under-another-element/ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the opacity of the `background` of your container `div`. When specifying `background-color`, you can opt for either 6 digits of hexadecimal number or 8 digits of hexadecimal number. When you opt for the 8-digit option, the last two digits represent the opacity of the color, from `00` meaning 0% opacity to `FF` meaning 100% opacity. For example: `#ffffff00` means white with 0% opacity and `#ffffff22` means white with around 13.28% opacity.

You can then create a background of white with a slightly stronger opacity on one side and a slightly weaker opacity on the other side using [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). One rather handy website to generate a gradient color in CSS is [here](https://cssgradient.io/).

Here's a simple example using `linear-gradient` and `box-shadow` to create the effect you want.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center url('https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/1/b/7/89060.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#on_top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 21%, rgba(180,255,255,0.15) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 19px 35px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>

<!-- Your translucent container -->
<div id="on_top"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's kinda what I needed but I wanted to know how to achieve this effect with slightly more difficult background like this: https://codepen.io/graffis/pen/ZEGoOdm where background of container perfectly match background of entire website.

Comment: @Graffis The same applies. You only need to define *one* translucent container **without** any child inside it. The link you provided showed that you used a lot of children to mimic the background-content. You need not do that.

Comment: @Graffis Here's an example **without** your needing to specify each content inside the translucent box: https://codepen.io/richard_w_here/pen/LYVmjGp. I've also modified my answer to show that the translucent box works with a *complex* background.

Comment: Thing is that the entire webiste should be inside of the 80x80% box so the content should stick to the "colors", that's why I created separate divs. I uploaded new picture in the main post to show you what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by `content` here? And what do you mean by `sticking to the colors`? Are you sure that this is still the same question? Your original question is about how to make it so that the 80%x80% box is the same color as the background (with a slight tint) from the example you've given.

Comment: Uploaded the pic :)

Comment: @Graffis The only matching background colour is the yellow part as far as I can see. **The concept is still the same**, you can create multiple boxes inside `#on_top`, then make some of the boxes transparent (that you want to match with the background), not colouring it yourself. Could you provide a link to the website where you got the screenshot?

Comment: I can't :( That's just a screenshot from designer's video tutorial.

Comment: @Graffis As mentioned, you can create multiple transparent boxes inside `#on_top` to match the background color behind it. Furthermore, your third picture doesn't exactly mimic the background color behind it (look at the grey, blue, and green section for example). Do note that the screenshot you provided is a mere concept and does not visually show us what happens when the viewport is shrunk. I highly recommend you think about that first.

Comment: @Graffis If your concern is to make "boxes" or "sections" inside `#on_top` based on the coloured "boxes" or "sections" on the background behind it, it'd be hard. I think that the only way would be to **manually** one at a time compute the values so that it aligns well even when the viewport is shrunk.